# I’m glad it ain’t your liver

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

What does 'liver' mean in context?

> “All right, Richard, my boy,” said old Anthony, cheerfully. “You may
>   run along down to your club now. **I’m glad it ain’t your liver.**

The first time 'liver' appears in this passage:

> “And that’s what I was coming to,” said the old man, less
>   boisterously. “That’s why I asked you to come in. There’s something
>   going wrong with you, boy. I’ve been noticing it for two weeks. Out
>   with it. I guess I could lay my hands on eleven millions within
>   twenty-four hours, besides the real estate. **If it’s your liver**,
>   there’s the Rambler(Rambler was an automobile brand name used by the Thomas B. Jeffery Company between 1900 and 1914.) down in the bay, coaled, and ready to steam down
>   to the Bahamas in two days.” “Not a bad guess, dad; you haven’t missed
>   it far.” “Ah,” said Anthony, keenly; “what’s her name?”

Strange writing style. There is not a word that his son is sick, not a word that he drinks, but his dad believes that son has a liver problems. Maybe dad is crazy, and there’s not a word about that either. Maybe "liver" has a figurative meaning?

Mammon and the Archer
by O. Henry

Comment: Can you provide a little more of the preceding context?

Comment: I gave more context.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know where it is quoted from but from context I believe that "liver" refers to the organ in the human body. The "run along down to your club" suggests going to an establishment that serves alcoholic drinks. The phrase "I’m glad it ain’t your liver" suggests that Richard may be meeting (at the club) someone who is fond of drinking and thus risking liver damage from alcohol poisoning.

Answer (score 0):

Excessive drinking is one cause of liver disease (cirrhosis).  People with this disease are strongly cautioned to avoid alcohol, which is hard from someone who has a history of (socially or not) enjoying a few drinks.

See the mayo clinic website for example: https://www.maylinic.org/diseases-conditions/cirrhosis/symptoms-causes/syc-20351487

It is likely that Anthony (presumably a doctor) has diagnosed Richard and determined that whatever it is/was that is/was bothering Richard is not related to the liver.  The liver being healthy, it is not (so) bad for Richard to have a few drinks, so he can head to the club (pub, or golf course club, where people also drink alcohol) to meet with his friends and have a few drinks.

There is another (not as likely) possibility - that Anthony is just a friend of Richard and after Richard told him that his liver is fine, Anthony was happy for him in that he could still enjoy going for a few drinks.

Answer (score 0):

Anthony, Richard's father, is concerned that he hasn't been behaving normally lately. He calls him in to find out what is going on. He suggests that perhaps Richard has a liver problem, presumably from too much drink, and offers the use of a boat (the Rambler) for a trip to the Bahamas, probably as a rest cure. He is relieved that Richard is merely in love, and isn't getting cirrhosis.

Comment: Strange writing style. There is not a word that his son is sick, not a word that he drinks, but his dad believes that son has a liver problems. Maybe dad is crazy, and there’s not a word about that either. Maybe "liver" has a figurative meaning?

Comment: It's a humorous short story. A lot is left to the inference of the reader. It may be a bit challenging for an English learner.